# Use text field in MATLAB GUI as timer

Tags: matlab, user-interface, text, matlab-figure

I have a simple GUI where I want to use a text field to display a constantly changing value generated in a loop. I just don't now how to get it working. From the help files and some forum thread I have the following:

First I create my text object:

```
hTimer  = uicontrol('Style','text','String','Time',...
           'Position',[450,300,60,15],...
           'Callback',@Timer_CreateFcn);
```

I create some function:

```
function Timer_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global statText
statText = hObject;
end
```

and then I have have my loop where the values are generated:

```
while ...
            textString=['TestCycleTime = ',num2str(datestr(tsNum(idx-5)-tsNumDoor(1),'MM:SS.FFF')),' [Min:Sec]'];
            global statText;
            set(statText, 'String', textString);
end
```

The script is running without errors, but still the timer is not updating. 
Could someone please give me a hint?

Comment: Why don't you update to a newer version of MATLAB which does have the GUIDE?

Comment: thats a thing you have to ask my boss...

Comment: There is absolutely no need for GUIDE. Your problem is timer management (which GUIDE doesn't help with). The timer should be initialised on its own in the GUI definition, **not** in the `text` uicontrol callback. The timer callback (which is accessible through the `TimerFcn` property) should be the one updating the text box.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are updating the `'String'` property of your text object within a `while` loop which prevents MATLAB from automatically taking the time to actually *render the change*. To alter this behavior, you can explicitly call [`drawnow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) after settings the `'String'` property to explicitly render the current figure.

```
set(hTimer, 'String', textString);
drawnow
```

As a side-note, I would recomment looking into the ways to pass data around your app rather than using `global` variables.